# Duplicate class error on Puppet Enterprise Hiera config

Tags: elasticsearch, hiera, puppet-enterprise

I'm getting the following error while running `puppet agent -t`

```
Duplicate declaration: Class[MyModule] is already declared; cannot redeclare on node mynode.mydomain.com
```

I'm using heira as my approach. In mynode.mydomain.com.yaml I have the following

```
classes:
  - MyModule:elasticsearch

mtd::elasticsearch::install_dir: /opt/es
mtd::elasticsearch::version: 1.5.1
mtd::elasticsearch::master_node: true
mtd::elasticsearch::data_node: true
mtd::elasticsearch::cluster: elasticsearch
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was quite simple.  The node was registered on the Web UI with the MyModule as a class already.  So deleting the node from the Web UI and then re-running `puppet agent -t` solved the problem.